# How to create a Dynamic ALV based on months?

Tags: dynamic, abap, alv

​I have a requirement to display in an ALV Grid, quantities based on month wise, but only show the month columns that have at least one non-zero value.

Now, the ALV shows like this:

```
matnr     0101    0102    0103  ...  0110    0111    0112
-----     ----    ----    ----       ----    ----    ----
0123         0       0       0          0     234     345
0124         0       0       0        458     234     345
```

but, it should display only:

```
matnr     0110    0111    0112
-----     ----    ----    ----
0123         0     234     345
0124       458     234     345
```

How to hide the month columns that have only zero values?

Comment: Be careful to preview your posts before publishing, the "table" was rendered in one line instead of several lines and several columns, it made your question unclear. I have updated it for you.

Comment: Question also asked on [SCN](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12701296/dynamic-alv-based-on-months.html), with currently one answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the field catalog of the ALV, which defines the way the columns are rendered, you may hide a column by either setting one of two properties or methods:

- if you use `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`, `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` `REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY`, set `NO_OUT` to 'X' or `TECH` to 'X'.
- if you use SALV, you have the class `CL_SALV_COLUMN` or its subclasses, which change these properties via the respective methods `SET_VISIBLE` or `SET_TECHNICAL`.

Both properties or methods hide the column, but the first one (NO_OUT, SET_VISIBLE) let the user the possibility to show the column via the layout options, while the second one (TECH, SET_TECHNICAL) hides the column definitely.

Of course, first you'll have to loop at the internal table and check the contents of each column. Because you say you have a "dynamic ALV", I guess you'll have to use ['ASSIGN COMPONENT'](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapassign_mem_area_dynamic_dobj.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_4@4@) to access the values of each row.